# how to combine the "TRUE FALSE" into "FALSE" using R?

Tags: r, logical-operators

I am using `%in%` to see if the vector contain what I need, like below:

```
> c(1,2)%in%1:4
[1] TRUE TRUE
> c(1,5)%in%1:4
[1]  TRUE FALSE
```

For the first case, I want the final outcome to be a single `TRUE` and for the second case, the outcome needs to be a single `FALSE` (i.e. like a AND truth table).

How can it be done?

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use all():

```
  R> all(c(1,2) %in% 1:4)
  [1] TRUE
  R> all(c(1,5) %in% 1:4)
  [1] FALSE
```

Comment: thanks! one extra question, any equivalent command for "OR", "NOR", "NAND" case?

Comment: I guess NAND would be `!all()`. And, as can be seen under `?all` (see also), `any()` would be the equivalent for OR (with `!any()` being the NOR).